# How do intellij.version and sinceBuild (untilBuild) relate to each other?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I have version in intellij block in build.gradle.kts:

```
intellij {
    version.set("2021.2.1")
    type.set("IC")
    plugins.set(listOf("android"))
}
```

and patchPluginXml:

```
patchPluginXml {
    sinceBuild.set("212")
    untilBuild.set("223.*")
}
```

here sinceBuild is set accordingly to intellij.version. but is this correct? which relations should have this properties? can I set sinceBuild lower than intellij.version?

Comment: Have you checked this article: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/tools-gradle-intellij-plugin.html#patchpluginxml-task-sincebuild ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `version` in the `intellij` block is the version (number) of IntelliJ gradle will use to build the plugin.
As a result, this is also the IntelliJ version used for the sandbox IDE when you run `gradle runIde`.

The `sinceBuild` and `untilBuild` are the version numbers that specify the range of IntelliJ versions the plugin (built with `version`) supports.
You basically give users a guarantee that your plugin works with any IntelliJ version within this range.
When you upload a plugin to the market place, your plugin will be verified against all these versions by the [IntelliJ Plugin Verifier](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-plugin-verifier).
You can also do this yourself with the [`runPluginVerifier` task](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/tools-gradle-intellij-plugin.html#runpluginverifier-task).

So, yes, you can set `sinceBuild` lower than `version` and probably should.
More often than not you want to test and build for the newest release while still supporting a few older versions.

With your current settings (`version` is `2021.2.1`, `sinceBuild` is `212`, and `untilBuild` is `223.*`), your plugin will be built with `2021.2.1` and you promise users that your plugin will work with any IntelliJ version from `2021.2.1` until `2022.3.*`.
When anyone tries to install your plugin with an IntelliJ older or newer than the specified range they will get a message saying that your plugin is not compatible with their IntelliJ version.

Comment: okay, so can we say that it's like targetSdk (intellij.version) and minSdk (sinceBuild) in Android or not?

Comment: Yeah, I guess that is similar. Though intellij.version is more like Androids compile sdk version than the target sdk version.